# What are the differences between pickle.dump/load and pickle.dumps/loads?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pickle

I've started to learn about the pickle module used for object serialization and deserialization.

I know that `pickle.dump` is used to store the code as a stream of bytes (serialization), and `pickle.load` is essentially the opposite, turning a stream of bytes back into a python object.  (deserialization).

But what are `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads`, and what are the differences between them and `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load`? I've looked at the documentation, but I am having trouble differentiating between the two.

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True, buffer_callback=None)
> ; Return the pickled representation of the object obj as a bytes object, instead of writing it to a file.

> pickle.loads(data, /, *, fix_imports=True, encoding="ASCII", errors="strict", buffers=None)
> Return the reconstituted object hierarchy of the pickled representation data of an object. data must be a bytes-like object.

Comment: _ instead of writing it to a file._ is what its all about. `load` and `dump` read from or write to files (or any object that looks like a file object). If you don't want to use files, `loads` and `dumps` use `bytes` objects. The "s" stands for string and harken back to python 2.x where bytes and strings were mostly the same thing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference between `dump` and `dumps` is that `dump` writes the pickled object to an open file, and `dumps` returns the pickled object as `bytes`. The file must be opened for writing in binary mode. The pickled version of the object is exactly the same with both `dump` and `dumps`.

So, if you did the following for object `obj`:

```
with open("pickle1", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
with open("pickle2", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(obj))
```

you'd end up with two files with exactly the same contents.

The same applies to loading - `load` "unpickles" from an open (readable) file object, and `loads` uses a `bytes` object.